# Checkbox in GridView not persistent ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox, persistence

I am having issues with this GridView. I update it in design mode, and the update does not make it to the code behind section. For example, I add field "xyz". Gridview says "xyz" fields exist in design mode. In code-behind, it does not exist. when you view the page in browser, ofcoure "xyz" field is not shown. After refresh, even the gridview looses this field in design mode. So ok I got around this problem and managed to add a template field which is now working.

Now the problem is, the checkbox that I added in one of the column is not persistent. I have a button which works on the selected values of checkboxes but each time I click the button, the page refereshes and all the checked values are lost (checked values becomes unchecked).

Does anyone has any idea?

Want to mention, I am working with a bit messy code. But dont want to change a lot at this time.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="All" >
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" name="chkAll" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server"  />     
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: A post back is most likely resetting the value held by chkAll. Perhaps you are rebinding the grid on post back

Comment: good point, but I just added this checkbox, it was not there in the original code. Rebinding makes sense but again it is just an extra field that I added. The rest of the columns are bound to the SQL datasource.

Comment: If i add `AutoPostBack="True"` it postbacks with its value lost. I added `OnCheckedChanged="debug_checkChanged"` to trace where the value is changing but that event is not firing either, even the checkbox value does change in postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a couple of days to figure out myself. Since my code was quite messy, it was hard to troubleshoot.

I put in some code in page_load default event that finally fixed. Don't know if I was putting code in the wrong place first. It definitely took some time though.